# How to self-host an ASP.Net Web Api on a home server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, owin

I am trying to find out how to host an asp.net web API online and one option is to self-host using OWIN. This, however, means running the application from Microsoft Visual Studio. I was wondering if I can use this method of hosting on a web server such that my API is live on the web. The reason why I am asking is I don't know if I can install Visual Studio on a Windows server and run it. How would I run a visual studio application on a web server?

Comment: Have you looked at this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api
You can self host as a Windows Service as well.

Comment: yeah, I saw that. My question is if I have to run it from Visual Studio, how do I run it from a web server? Does it mean I would have to install Visual Studio on a web server?

Comment: If you create a Console Application or a Windows Service, then you can just run your application. There is no need for a web service like IIS or Visual Studio in your web server machine

Comment: Understood, thank you very much

Comment: Another question, how would I change the IP of the app so that it is live on the web and not just the local machine?

Comment: You can use something like `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` to get the host name and use it as your URL for listening

Comment: That makes sense, thanx again